# Assign value to array (Python, Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have initialized an array in the form of

```
for x in range(0,21000): 
    if np.amax(probability[x]) > 0.2:
        i = i+1
```

`Label = np.zeros(shape=(i,130))`

and now with the following for cycle I would like to assign the value to each row of Label

```
for x in range(0,21000):
    if np.amax(probability[x]) > 0.2:
        Label[i] = [feature[x],y[x],np.amax(probability)[x]]
    i = i+1
```

Where feature is an array 128*21000. 
Unfortunately, I keep receving the following error:

```
Label[i] = [feature[x],y[x],np.amax(probability)[x]]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: You probably want to provide the `axis` value for the `np.amax` call otherwise it returns a scalar: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html

Comment: This isn't coming from the assignment, but from `np.amax(probability)[x]`, where you're trying to index a scalar.  When in doubt about something try each expression individually and see what you get.

Comment: Sorry  there was a typo, i will fix the question

Comment: Please don't change your question mid-stream.  Earlier you were asking about a different error.

Comment: Okey, sorry I dind't know that. Can I ask another question ?

Comment: I'm lost. The error message keeps changing everytime I read the question. Please append additional information when making edits instead of changing the old content

Comment: You can always ask another question. Sometimes it is even appropriate to update your current question with new information if the new question arises from comments on the current question.

Comment: I edit the question, but then I was told to cancel the editing.

Comment: BTW, if you are using plain Python `for` loops on a Numpy array there's a very good chance that you're doing it the wrong way, and that there's a Numpy operation that can perform the same task at C speed instead of Python speed.

Comment: What the same operation in this case would be?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a single scalar value for `np.amax` but rather an array of values. Therefore you need to specify a specific axis for the call as follows:

```
np.amax(probability, axis=1)
```

You can see examples of the use of the `axis` argument from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

Or if you really do want to use the scalar value, don't index it using `[x]` in `np.amax(probability)[x]`